# IBM MobileFirst Platform - Any IBM certified list of JavaScript GUI, MVC frameworks?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to find out a list of JavaScript GUI, MVC frameworks that are certified by IBM for IBM MobileFirst hybrid/web app development. I know MobileFirst studio comes with tooling support for DOJO and JQuery Mobile. Sencha Touch tooling is deprecated in MobileFirst Platform version 6.3. MobileFirst Platform framework is open to integrate any third party JavaScript libraries such as Bootstrap.js, Backbone.js etc. with it.

If anyone knows about such a list IBM has published with the certified JavaScript GUI, MVC frameworks for app development kindly let me know. I have Googled around and searched the MobileFirst documentation but unable to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such list of certified frameworks for exactly the reasons you have mentioned in your question. MobileFirst Platform is open to any framework you would like to use.

If you happen to encounter a rare problem in the product the prevents working with some framework, you can notify us about it and we'll see that it is resolved, but other than that - there is no list of certified frameworks. Use whichever one that you would like.